# Computed data not updating in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework

I am using quasar framework and vuex for my app. The parent component is rendering child components with the data from vuex store. The child component is contenteditable and if i press enter key on it, the store is updated. But the computed property in parent component is not updating.
Here is my code:

**parent-component.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-for="(object, objKey) in objects"
         :key="objKey">
        <new-comp
                :is=object.type
                :objId="object.id"
        ></new-comp>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from './child-component';

export default {
    name: 'ParentComponent',
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    },
    computed : {
        objects(){
            return this.$store.state.objects.objects;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.assignEnterKey();
    },
    methods: {
        assignEnterKey() {
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
                if(e.which === 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**child-component.vue**

```
<template>
  <div contenteditable="true" @keydown.enter="addChildComp" class="child-container">
    Tell your story
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'ChildComponent',
    props: ['objId'],
    data() {
        return {
            id: null
        }
    },
    computed : {
        serial(){
            return this.$store.state.objects.serial;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addChildComp() {
            let newId = this.objId + 1;
            let newSerial = this.serial + 1;
            this.$store.commit('objects/updateObjs', {id: newId, serial: newSerial});
        }
    }
}
```

**state.js**

```
export default {
 serial: 1,
 objects: {
     1:
       {
       "id" : 1,
       "type" : "ChildComponent",
       "content" : ""
     }
 }
}
```

**mutation.js**

```
export const updateObjs = (state, payload) => {
  let id = payload.id;
  let serial = payload.serial;
  state.objects[serial] = {
    "id" : id ,
    "type" : "ChildComponent",
    "content" : ""
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vuex mutations [follow](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) general Vue.js reactivity rules, this means that Vue.js [reactivity traps](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) are applicable to vuex mutations.

In order to maintain reactivity, when adding a property to `state.objects` you should either:

- Use the special [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) method:

  ```
   Vue.set(state.objects, serial, { id, "type" : "ChildComponent", "content" : ""})
  ```
- Or, recreate `state.objects` object instead of mutating it:

  ```
   state.objects = { ...state.objects, [serial]: { id, "type" : "ChildComponent", "content" : ""} }
  ```